# SQL Database Table Joining to create an IdealTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I need some helps to join the tables I have currently.

Leave, Overtime And Roster's Date, EmployeeID need to match

Note: ShiftDuration is set to default value = 8.25

Note: Leave and Overtime table will only have entries when an employee applies for leave and overtime.

```
Employee
EmplyeeeID | Username | Password | GivenName | FamilyName | TeamID | ContactNo | StaffType
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123         123        abc        John          Snow        1         999          1
  1234        1234       abcd       Jack         Waller       2         223          1 
  12345       12345      abcde       Ali           Saw        1         123          1
  123456      123456     abcdef     Peter         Peter       2         223          1
  1234567     1234567    abcdeg     Bryan         Peter       1         333          1


Roster
Duty_ID | EmployeeID |      Date        | ShiftType | ShiftDuration
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   2       123             2018-05-05         1          8.25
   4       1234            2018-05-04         1          8.25
   5       12345           2018-05-05         1          8.25
   7       123456          2018-05-04         1          8.25
   8       1234567         2018-05-05         1          8.25


Overtime
OTID | EmployeeID |     Date     | OT_Duration | OT_Reason
------------------------------------------------------------
 2        1234        2018-05-04        2        Cover Duty

Leave
LeaveID | EmployeeID |   Date    | Duration_Off | Reason
----------------------------------------------------------
 3            123      2018-05-05        2         NIL


IdealTable (Via Query)
   Date    | EmployeeID | GivenName | FamilyName | TeamID | ShiftType | ShiftDuration | Duration_Off | OT_Duration | Total_Hours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-05-05      123         John         Snow         1         1             8.25            2             0            6.25
2018-05-04      1234        Jack        Waller        1         1             8.25            0             2            10.25
2018-05-05      12345       Ali           Saw         1         1             8.25            0             0            8.25
2018-05-04      123456      Peter         Peter       1         1             8.25            0             0            8.25
2018-05-05      1234567     Bryan         Peter       1         1             8.25            2             0            8.25
```

I have 4 tables, they are Employee, Leave, Overtime, Roster

```
Employee
-EmployeeID (PK)
-Username
-Password
-GivenName
-FamilyName
-TeamID
-ContactNo
-StaffType

Leave
-LeaveID (PK)
-EmployeeID (FK)
-Date
-Duration_Off
-Reason

Overtime
-OTID (PK)
-EmployeeID (FK)
-Date
-OT_Duation
-OT_Reason

Roster
-DutyID (PK)
-EmployeeID (FK)
-Date
-ShiftType
-Shift Duration (Default Value = 8.25)
```

What I am trying to do is join the data from this 4 tables using Query

```
Ideal Table
-Date (From Leave, Overtime and Roster Table)
-EmployeeID (Employee Table)
-GivenName (Employee Table)
-FamilyName (Employee Table)
-TeamID (Employee Table)
-ShiftType (Roster Table)
-ShiftDuration (Roster Table)
-Duration_Off (Leave Table)
-OT_Duration (Overtime Table)
-Total_Hours (Calculation from joint table [(ShiftDuration + OT_Duration) - Duration_Off]
```

[My database diagram design](https://i.gyazo.com/76394f96149a2f8602b9b33d62330ddb.png) Do ignore the TimeData table as I initially wanted to use the TimeData table to achieve the IdealTable

My current query

```
USE [SMRT Dashboard]
GO

;With Dates
AS
(
SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.Roster
UNION 
SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.Leave
UNION
SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.Overtime
),
Work_Matrix
AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID,[Date],ShiftType,ShiftDuration,CAST(NULL AS Decimal(30,2)) AS Duration_Off,CAST(NULL AS Decimal(30,2)) AS OT_Duration
FROM dbo.Roster
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID,[Date], NULL, NULL,Duration_Off
FROM dbo.Leave
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID,[Date],NULL,NULL,NULL,OT_Duration
FROM dbo.Overtime
)

SELECT d.[Date],
e.EmployeeID,
e.GivenName,
e.FamilyName,
e.TeamID,
w.ShiftType,
w.ShiftDuration,
w.Duration_Off,
w.OT_Duration,
w.Total_Hours
FROM  Dates d
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT EmployeeID,
[Date],
MAX(ShiftType) AS ShiftType,
SUM(ShiftDuration) AS ShiftDuration,
SUM(Duration_Off) AS Duration_Off,
SUM(OT_Duration) AS OT_Duration,
SUM(ShiftDuration) + SUM(OT_Duration) - SUM(Duration_Off) AS Total_Hours
FROM Work_Matrix
GROUP BY EmployeeID,
[Date]
)w
ON d.[Date] = w.[Date]
JOIN dbo.Employee e
ON e.EmployeeID = w.EmployeeID
```

Current Errors:

```
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you post your attempt

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Read joins manual of SQL.

Comment: @XING I tried INNER JOINing Roster and Employee together, but I get Incorrect syntax near 'EmployeeID' as an error. [Error](https://gyazo.com/38d0566ada788a5003a1526b90d48b35)

Comment: Please add your query to the question

Comment: Remove the asterisk from the query.

Comment: Select * will select all fields from all referenced tables, if you really want that you should add a , after the *.

Comment: @nicomp @P.Salmon I removed the asterisk from the query, I am getting these error: `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
        Ambiguous column name 'EmployeeID'.`

Comment: @envals, where identically named columns exist in more than one table, you need to qualify which column you're asking for. So, `Employee.EmployeeID` (to differentiate it from all the other tables which have an `EmployeeID` column, like Roster). Personally, I have adopted the principle of giving each table a unique prefix (an abbreviation of its name) and prefixing foreign keys so that this ambiguity never arises - so in Employees, you'd have a column `em_employee_id` and in Roster, you'd have a column `ro_em_employee_id`.

Comment: @Steve, Youre are suggesting that I change the name of "EmployeeID" in all the table to make it clearer?

Comment: If you want someone to give you an answer that actually works you should add sample data to your question as text (or to sqlfiddle) together with expected output based on the sample data.

Comment: @envals, that's just a tip for you to consider based on part of what I've found to be the most convenient naming conventions - others may disagree, so I don't want to recommend it. Working within your existing database design, you'd just qualify the column reference as I've explained.

Comment: "this is for my Final Semester Project who I did not study for." -- Sigh!

Comment: Poor title. Edit to summarize the core of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this but you may now check this. Hope your problem will be solved.

```
SELECT 
a.EmployeeID,
a.GivenName,
a.FamilyName,
a.TeamID,
d.ShiftType,
d.ShiftDuration,
b.Duration_Off,
c.OT_Duration,
b.Date,
(d.ShiftDuration + c.OT_Duration) - b.Duration_Off as Total_Hours
FROM Employee a
INNER JOIN Roster d ON  a.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID 
LEFT JOIN Leave b ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID 
LEFT JOIN Overtime c ON  a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
```

I assume `Date` is same from all three tables (Leave, Overtime and Roster Table)

Comment: It works! but I am not getting any data, as my leave, Overtime are empty. Is it possible to show data with those tables empty? [Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/35996f64847c00f4588ffc6b40a0d78e.png)

Comment: Check if all tables have data + check if IDs are same at least for one, then you should have something :)

Comment: Look online for the sets theory, remember that joins behave as intersections

Comment: @dipakdutta `Leave And Overtime` shouldn't have data all the time, as it should have data only when Employees apply or leave or Supervisors added them to the Overtime list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select 
l.Date,
o.Date,
r.Date,
e.EmployeeID,
e.GivenName,
e.FamilyName,
e.TeamID,
r.ShiftType,
r.ShiftDuration,
l.Duration_Off,
o.OT_Duration,
((r.ShiftDuration+o.OT_Duration)-l.Duration_Off) as Total_Hours
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Leave l ON e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Overtime o ON  e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Roster r ON  r.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query ! You will get the correct output .

```
SELECT 
e.EmployeeID AS 'Emp ID',
e.GivenName AS 'Emp Name',
l.Date AS Date,
e.FamilyName AS 'Family Name',
e.TeamID AS 'Team ID',
r.ShiftType AS 'Shift Type',
r.ShiftDuration AS 'Shift Duration',
l.Duration_Off AS 'Duration Off',
o.OT_Duration AS 'OT Duration',
(r.ShiftDuration + o.OT_Duration) - l.Duration_Off as 'Total Hours'
FROM 
Employee e,
Leave l,
Overtime o,
Roster r
WHERE
e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
AND
e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
AND
e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that an employee may have leave, may have overtime, or neither. By using INNER JOIN, you're filtering down the set of employees to ones that have Leave, and on a Roster, and have Overtime.

I created a SqlFiddle with the data you present (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f7d8e/20/0)) that should get you closer.

```
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(r.Date, o.Date, l.Date) as Date,
    e.EmployeeID,
    e.GivenName,
    e.FamilyName,
    e.TeamID,
    r.ShiftType,
    r.ShiftDuration,
    IFNULL(l.Duration_Off, 0) as Duration_Off,
    IFNULL(o.OT_Duration, 0) as OT_Duration,
    r.ShiftDuration + IFNULL(o.OT_Duration, 0) - IFNULL(l.Duration_Off, 0) as Total_Hours
  FROM Employee e
  INNER JOIN Roster r on
    e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN Overtime o on
    e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  LEFT JOIN `Leave` l on
    e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
```

There's a few cavaets that this query won't solve:

- If an employee has multiple leave entries or multiple overtime entries, the person will be listed N times. You can potentially use a GROUP BY statement to deal with this
- The sample data in your question doesn't reconcile correctly. For example, Employe 1234 has a shift on 5/4/2018 and OT on 5/5/2018 but gets 10.25 on 5/4/2018.

If you use TimeData, this becomes a lot easier (assuming one record per date per employee):

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(r.Date, o.Date, l.Date) as Date,
  e.EmployeeID,
  e.GivenName,
  e.FamilyName,
  e.TeamID,
  r.ShiftType,
  IFNULL(r.ShiftDuration, 0) as ShiftDuration,
  IFNULL(l.Duration_Off, 0) as Duration_Off,
  IFNULL(o.OT_Duration, 0) as OT_Duration,
  IFNULL(r.ShiftDuration, 0) + IFNULL(o.OT_Duration, 0) - IFNULL(l.Duration_Off, 0) as Total_Hours
from TimeData t
INNER JOIN Employee e on
  t.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Roster r on
  t.Duty_ID = r.Duty_ID
LEFT JOIN Overtime o on
  t.OTID = o.OTID
LEFT JOIN `Leave` l on
  t.LeaveID = l.LeaveID
```

Example SqlFiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76601/1/0)

Comment: How do you suggest I use TimeData? I don't have any idea on how to use them. As I can't think of any way of using the TimeData Table without any inputs.

Comment: Do you test data for TimeData? From your database diagram, it seemed to represent a way of tying the various tables together for a given employee. In my second query, I use TimeData to join the tables together and populate the appropriate fields without having to do a GROUP BY.

Comment: I don't have test data for TimeData as based on my understanding by using TimeData table I would need to key in the different ID by hand.